# Viewing images in a web browser

Tags: browser, images

I'd like to view large images from my local filesystem through a web browser. The problem I'm having is that the images are only displayed at "fit to screen" or "100%"

Is there good way (Firefox plugin, etc) to handle viewing large images? I'm looking for stuff like zoom control and easy navigation around the image. Ideally, I'd even get something like the way Gwenview remembers zoom/location when switching between images.

**EDIT:**
I'd like the user to have control over the zoom level or the image (maybe a slider?) and I need the ability to capture the zoom level and location so that I can load another image at the same location, with the same zoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Firefox add-on? May be *Image Zoom* Ff add-on...

Here's the developper web site:  http://imagezoom.yellowgorilla.net/

Answer (score 5):

[Google Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95346) does this by default (click to zoom, and scroll-bars appear).
If you want a more incremental zoom, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

If you want more than that, you have to be more specific about what other features you need.

Comment: Does clicking not zoom to 100%? What about zooming to 50%?

Comment: @ajwood, see edit.

Comment: Does my edit make it clear?

Comment: In Chrome's Wrench menu, you can choose the zoom level of a webpage between 25% and 500% at certain increments. This also works with images.

Answer (score 2):

[Opera](http://www.opera.com/) handles large images just fine by default, similar to Chrome. If you have the status bar set to visible (or you could customise the URL bar to include that if you value screen real estate), you'll get a visual zoom control, or just use the keys or Ctrl+scroll to zoom. Dragging the mouse navigates around the image, as does using the cursor keys; clicking toggles between fit-to-screen and 100% view types, and if you drag a different image onto the same tab, it will remember your zoom level (though you may have to click to toggle view type). It will even remember your last zoom level if you resurrect a previously closed tab from the trash can.

I'm sure you could whack something together with some [User JavaScript](http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/) if you need it to be fancier than that. Or you could try the [Image Autosizer](https://addons.opera.com/en/addons/extensions/details/image-autosizer/2.0/?display=en) extension.